# Youtube's HTML 5 player freezes all the time, how do I disable that and force flash on Safari

Tags: youtube, html, web-browser

I hate Flash but Youtube's HTML5 player stinks on Safari.

**[See this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCd92aaVPo4&feature=youtu.be)** it freezes all the time on Safari (El Cap). I watch movies from this guy, almost every movie he posts freezes on Safari. It is annoying as hell.

Any way to solve that?

Comment: Just watched it (didn't understand a word ;) - but not one freeze. I think it's more likely to be your connection, or proximity to your nearest CDN, rather than anything inherent in Safari itself. Reboot all your network hardware, then the Mac; wire up if you're on wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download YouTube App from App store. It runs better when you watch videos on YouTube official App.

Comment: Thanks. I think that is the best solution so far. Google should fix things like that or it will sound like it is done in bad faith to make people move to chrome.